# Grok Patterns ElasticSearch

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, logging, grok, logbook

i don't find grok pattern for the following message for ElasticSearch.

```bash
Outgoing Response: CUR-d13cfb432b1064f0
Duration: 11 ms
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Total-Count, X-Result-Count
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 27 Jul 2023 11:05:30 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

{"code":"22","message":"[FIELD =>] organizationInterlocutor.contactMedium.emailAddress [DETAIL_OF_MESSAGE => ] doit correspondre à \"^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$\"","description":"Invalid body"}
```

thank you for helping.

I try this pattern :

%{JAVALOGMESSAGE}

I want in the new field for each specific information in the text.

for example :

```json
"Duration" : "11 ms"
```

Comment: Do you only need "Duration" field?

Comment: i want all the information please, Duration is juste an example, thank you

Comment: You can use the logstash multiline-codec-plugin for that.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html